# Why this script doesnt work with larger numbers/values

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code doesnt work perfectly with larger numbers? Can someone explain why? Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesnt?

```
$('.Count').each(function () {
var $this = $(this);
 jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'swing',
   step: function () {
    $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: how big is "larger" ?

Comment: ok, now define "doesn't work perfectly".  FWIW, the answer to your problem is probably to avoid abusing the jQuery animation function for this sort of trick.

Comment: If you mean large numbers on the duration, maybe it just looks like it doesn't work. Since it's `swing`, the initial steps would take a lot longer to start, giving the impression that it's not working, when in fact, is veeery slow.

Comment: The animation doesnt count up to the value specified. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `step` callback is not necessarily called for every possible number in the sequence.

Add this to the `options` parameter to `.animate`:

```
complete: function () {
    $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
}
```

this ensures that the final value is shown.  See http://jsfiddle.net/3qfjta79/